# how to access an element from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a cart view following a tutorial and I need to print out the quantity of an item. I have two functions in utils.py from where I wanna access the quantity element and print it out in a view, currently getting an error `'dict' object has no attribute 'quantity'`

```
def cookieCart(request):
    try:
        cart = json.loads(request.COOKIES['cart'])
    except:
        cart = {}

    print('Cart:', cart)
    items = []
    order = {'get_cart_total': 0, 'get_cart_items': 0, 'shipping': False}
    cartItems = order['get_cart_items']

    for i in cart:
        try:
            cartItems += cart[i]["quantity"]
            product = Product.objects.get(id=i)
            total = (product.final_price * cart[i]["quantity"])
            order['get_cart_total'] += total
            order['get_cart_items'] += cart[i]["quantity"]

            item = {
                'product':{
                    'id':product.id,
                    'name':product.name,
                    'final_price':product.final_price,
                    'image_URL':product.image_URL,
                },

                **#print the quantity on view**

                'quantity':cart[i]["quantity"],
                'get_total':total,
                }
            items.append(item)

        except:
            pass

    return {"items": items, "order": order, "cartItems": cartItems}

def cartData(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        cartItems = order.get_cart_items
    else:
        cookieData = cookieCart(request)
        cartItems = cookieData['cartItems']
        order = cookieData['order']
        items = cookieData['items']
    return {'cartItems':cartItems ,'order':order, 'items':items}
```

Views

```
from .utils import cookieCart, cartData

def my_view(request):
    data = cartData(request)    
    items = data['items']
    qty = items[0].quantity   
    print(qty)
```

Data Structure:
if I print out 'items' instead of 'qty' the data looks like this

```
[{"product": {"id": 9, "name": "p_one", "final_price": 59, "image_URL": "/images/p_one.jpg"}, "quantity": 2, "get_total": 118}, {"product": {"id": 10, "name": "p_two", "final_price": 32, "image_URL": "/images/p_two.jpg"}, "quantity": 3, "get_total": 96}]
```

Comment: Can you show the full [traceback](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-traceback) error?

Comment: `unhashable type: 'list'` means that your **key** of hash has become **list**. This error occurs when trying to hash a list, which is an unhashable object. Yes it would be better to debug if you could add full stacktrace here. Also add print hash before function end so that we can debugging would be easier!!

Comment: @codester_09 added traceback, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's decompose your view :

```py
data = cartData(request)
```

cartData returns a dict where {"items": list of dicts, ... }

```
items = data['items']
```

At this point, `items`'s value is a list of dicts.
To access the first item of a list you use integers indices like

```py
myList[0] # first item in "myList"
myList[1] # second item in "myList"
etc
```

So here, remember this is a list that contains dicts.
So Items[0] = a dict that is defined in your cookieCart function

```py
item = {
                'product':{
                    'id':product.id,
                    'name':product.name,
                    'final_price':product.final_price,
                    'image_URL':product.image_URL,
                },

                **#print the quantity on view**

                'quantity':cart[i]["quantity"],
                'get_total':total,
                }
```

this dict has 3 keys : "product", "quantity" and "get_total".

To access a dict key's value, you use this syntax :

```
myDict["the key"] # As opposed to lists, you use string keys to match values
```

So to get the quantity in your case, we could decompose like this :

```py
order = cartData(request) # dict
all_items_in_cart_list = order["items"] # list
first_item_in_cart = all_items_in_cart_list[0] # dict again
quantity_of_first_item = first_item_in_cart["quantity"] # your value !
```

Comment: yh quantity is a field of the class OrderItem

Comment: @betty_ I've added the solution to answer, tell me if this works. Basically you access first element of the queryset, then you access its quantity field's value.

Comment: It gives me 'dict' object has no attribute 'quantity', but it does!

Comment: Try items[0]["quantity"] then, maybe you could see what the dict holds with items[0].items() ?

Comment: yh this actually worked! Can u please explain what happened? Also, edit the answer and I'll accept it as the correct one! thx so much

Comment: @betty_ sure, i've edited the Answer with the breakdown. Happy to help !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how does your data look like, but this is where the problem might be:

```py
def my_view(request):
    data = cartData(request)    
    qty = data['items']['quantity']
    # qty = data['items',['quantity']]    
    print(qty)
```

Comment: Doing that throws me a KeyError 'item' on the terminal, I added traceback please have a look! thx

Comment: @betty_ Now run the above code.

Comment: @codester_09 This is what I get, TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: This is to give you an example of how to solve your issue. The problem was in incorrect use of the brackets operator. We can't guess the format of your data. You access the dict keys by `['attribute']` operator and list elements by `[0]` where 0 is some arbitrary index you should know.